# Scraping json content from a site ordered in pages

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape a site, when I run the following code without `region_id=`[any number from one to 32] I get a [500], but if I set region_id=1 I'll get only a first page by default (on the url it is `pagina=&`), pages are up to 500; is there a command or parameter for retrieving every page (every possible value of `pagina=`), avoiding for loops?

```
import requests

url = "http://www.enciclovida.mx/explora-por-region/especies-por-grupo?utf8=%E2%9C%93&grupo_id=Plantas&region_id=&parent_id=&pagina=&nombre="

resp = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})

data = resp.json()
```

Comment: Why would you want to avoid for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even without a for loop, you are still going to need iteration. You could do it with recursion or map as I've done below, but the iteration is still there. This solution has the advantage that everything is a generator, so only when you ask for a page's json from all_data will url be formatted, the request made, checked and converted to json. I added a filter to make sure you got a valid response before trying to get the json out. It still makes every request sequentially, but you could replace map with a parallel implementation quite easily.

```
import requests
from itertools import product, starmap
from functools import partial

def is_valid_resp(resp):
    return resp.status_code == requests.codes.ok

def get_json(resp):
    return resp.json()

# There's a .format hiding on the end of this really long url, 
# with {} in appropriate places
url = "http://www.enciclovida.mx/explora-por-region/especies-por-grupo?utf8=%E2%9C%93&grupo_id=Plantas&region_id={}&parent_id=&pagina={}&nombre=".format
regions = range(1, 33)
pages = range(1, 501)
urls = starmap(url, product(regions, pages))

moz_get = partial(requests.get, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
responses = map(moz_get, urls)

valid_responses = filter(is_valid_response, responses)
all_data = map(get_json, valid_responses)
# all_data is a generator that will give you each page's json.
```

Comment: code is short and  fast, I helped a friend find his way and he accomplished the scrapping in php, I would have done it parallelized in R, but I've heard python excels in scrapping. How did you find the .format?

Comment: .format is one of the standard ways to format strings. It's a function so here I'm partially applying it to the URL string and assigning it to the variable called url. starmap is what actually calls the function. This isn't exactly the most Pythonic way to do it, for that you'd use for loops and it would look more like the Python you seen in tutorials.